# Regex to get a price, ignoring currency and separators

Tags: number-formatting, regex-group, currency-formatting

I'm trying to find a standard regex (Python?) which will extract a positive or negative price disregarding the optional currency symbol, optional comma or dot thousand seperator, and optional decimal seperator (but if it's there make it a dot).

So:
1,234.56
£ 1,234.56
£ 1234,56
€1.234,56
All output one group: 1234.56

likewise:
-1,234.56
£ -1,234.56
£ -1234,56
€-1.234,56
All output one group: -1234.56

Could anyone suggest a suitable option? Thanks!

I've tried a couple of expressions, some have come close, but none have managed to provide a single group which meets all of the criteria

Comment: Going by the data you provided, you could try this, `\b(\d)(?:,|.)?(\d+)(?=(?:,|.)?\d\d)(?:,|.)?(\d\d)\b`, https://regex101.com/r/BUOo8D/1.

Comment: Thanks, but with the 1.234,56 variations, I still get 1.234,56 (not 1234.56), and with 1,234.56 I still get 1,234.56 (not 1234.56). Apologies if I'm testing wrong (with https://regex101.com/), or if what I'm trying to do isn't possible :)